# Write output in different directories

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, scalding

Are there any settings that I can use to make the output go in a separate timestamped (give a format) directory every time I run the job?

I use the following Scalding code to write my flow output:

```
val out = TypedPipe[MyType]
out.write(PackedAvroSource[MyType]("my/output/path"))
```

By default Scalding replaces the output in the `my/output/path` directory in HDFS. I'd like the output to go into a different `my/output/path/MMDDyyyyHHmm/` path depending on when the job runs. I am about to write some utils to add a timestamp to the path myself by I'd rather use some existing ones if available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate the date to the directory.

```
Date date = new Date();
String direct = "my/output/" + date.toString();
out.write(PackedAvroSource[MyType](direct));
```

For more information on date and time click [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)

Comment: Yes I could do that but I was hoping that the use case was common enough to have a prebuilt scalding option for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PartitionedDelimited` sink to write to multiple directories. See comments in https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/scalding-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/scalding/typed/PartitionedDelimitedSource.scala for more info.

This would preclude you from using AVRO format, but perhaps you could write `PartitionedPackedAvro`?

Comment: This sounds a hack (I actually need all the output to go into a new single folder each time) around the use of vertical partitioning. That could work I guess. I was hoping not to have to write any code though...